# Segmentation Fault in tf::MessageFilter

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6536f2b in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

line:

    laser_notifier_ = new tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>(laser_sub_,listener_, target_frame_, 10);

Backtrace
---------

0  0x00007ffff6536f2b in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

1  0x0000000000442f60 in getTFPrefix (this=<optimized out>)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/tf.h:329

2  tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > >::setTargetFrames (this=0x7fffffffc998, 
    target_frames=...) at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/message_filter.h:211

3  0x0000000000451c91 in setTargetFrame (target_frame=..., this=0x7fffffffc998)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/message_filter.h:195

4  MessageFilter<message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > > > (max_rate=..., 
    nh=<error reading variable: access outside bounds of object referenced via synthetic pointer>, queue_size=10, 
    target_frame=..., tf=..., f=..., this=0x7fffffffc998)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/message_filter.h:156


5  LaserLineExtractor::LaserLineExtractor (this=0x7fffffffc3b0, n=..., base_link=..., odom_link=...)
    at src/lines.cpp:148


6  0x0000000000430b87 in main (argc=1, argv=<optimized out>)
    at src/lines.cpp:885
```

It seems as though tf_prefix_ is not initialized properly which is causing this segfault.

```
Ros version - fuerte
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

uname -a:
Linux desktop 3.0.0-32-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 28 22:32:30 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59611/segmentation-fault-in-tf::messagefilter/) by [itzsid](https://answers.ros.org/users/4570/itzsid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If this is still an issue. Please create a minimal demonstration and submit an issue on github: https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0